# How to convert taxonomy term name to term id at time of importing and create custom node from csv in drupal?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting

I am creating content type programmatically. I am importing content from csv file.. Everything working fine. But I am not able to select category at the time of import like other fields.. and how to convert term name to term id ,because csv giving me term name.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the term object if you pass it the term name:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7

There is an example at the bottom of that link